# Creating a different activity within main activity triggered by a button

Tags: java, android

I have rather simple task to complete, but I can't get my head around it, I have my main class here, I choosing between screens using buttons, My task is to create a About page just explaing the rules of the game (my application).

```
public class Hashi_Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
      View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
      continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

      View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
      newButton.setOnClickListener(this);

      View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
      aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

      View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
      exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

  // click handling
  public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.exit_button:
    finish();
    break;
      case R.id.new_button:
    NewGame();
    break;
    case R.id.about_button:
        NewGame();
        break;
    }
  }
```

And here i create a my NewGame activity this all works.

```
public void NewGame() {
    // We first ask for the difficulty level.
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle(R.string.new_game_title)
      // we provide a char array with the on click listener.
      .setItems(R.array.difficulty,
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int hardness) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Hashi_Main.this, HashiGame.class);
          intent.putExtra(HashiGame.KEY_DIFFICULTY, hardness);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
      })
    .show();
  }
```

What I want to do is the same thing but to use it for about page, I want to use TextView for the rules, this activity will have nothing else except text and a back to main menu button. I tried something like this.

```
public void About() {
        LinearLayout lheader = new LinearLayout(this);
        lheader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView about_rules = new TextView(this);
        about_rules.setId(about_id);
        lheader.addView(about_rules);

    }
```

But I am stuck for a while now, how can i trigger this activity?

Comment: `About` is not an activity. If you want to create a new activity, with a new layout, you have to create a new Activity class (e.g. `public class About extends Activity`) and launch it with an intent and a call to `startActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an about activity and use an intent to launch your newly created activity. like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Hashi_Main.this, AboutActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ahh yea I was thinking in the wrong direction I knew that there is a simple solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any Activity in the About() method. It is just a local LinearLayout with a TextView.

You need to learn more about Android development before making any app.

Comment: This is not an answer...it is a comment, please either edit your post to provide  a solution or delete this post. (Yes, I know you do not have the required reputation to comment.)

Comment: Do let me know the magic to comment without enough reputation, please.

And, I think learning Android Development is the solution to the question.

Comment: No magic! Just work--like everything else in life. And if "... learning Android Development is the solution..."  was the solution than SO would have a very short and dull existence.